# Syntax error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the right syntax to use near '****' at line 1

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm creating a login form in c#. When I run it I get an error at `MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();`

Error: *(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the right syntax to use near 'login' at line 1).*

I can't find what's wrong with the SQL syntax. Can someone help me please?

CODE:

```
private void BtLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            con.ConnectionString = @"server=;user id=;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=myadministration;password=";

            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "select * login";
            MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                if (TbUsername.Text.Equals(dr["user"].ToString()) && PbPswd.Password.Equals(dr["paswd"].ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
                }

            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This is not how to do a login check. Storing raw passwords is _very bad_ and should not even be done for testing/learning/proof of concept code. Even encryption is not good enough. Instead, you must use a cryptographic (not md5) hash. When someone tries to login, you use the same hash procedure on the attempted password and then compare the hashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, you have a syntax error in your query. When querying a database object you need to use the `from` keyword.

Convert your query to `select * from login` and it will work.

Comment: great. Kindly upvote and accept as answer to help users in the future :)